# Why not using "new" affects performance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, object, prototype, new-operator

The link to below explains what happens when we use the "new" keyword https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/new-keyword-in-javascript .

I.E. I can declare object1 for some random constructor function below.

```js
const object1 = new ConstructorFunction(1,2,3)
```

However, if I apparently replicate the code with the code below,

```js
const _object1 = {};

_object1.__proto__ = ConstructorFunction.prototype;

const object1 = ConstructorFunction.call(_object1,1,2,3);
```

then apparently this code will have performance issues, since I have changed the [[prototype]] at runtime (this warning is also given on MDN in the section about changing an objects [[prototype]]. It basically states that it should not be done.) I have been told I can get around this by changing the code above to.

```js
 const _object1 = Object.create(ConstructorFunction.prototype);

 const object1 = ConstructorFunction.call(_object1,1,2,3);
```

So I am not sure why "Object.create" is better. I get that I am creating a blank object with the required [[prototype]] rather than creating a normal object and then changing its [[prototype]], so it is quicker. However, apparently creating a blank object with the required [[prototype]] means creating a normal blank object and then manually changing it. So presumably Object.create source code is something like:

```js
const Object.create = function(prototype) {
  const newObject = {};
  newObject.__proto__ = prototype;
  return newObject;
};
```

This is pretty much the same as what I initially did, except, it is wrapped in a function. Basically, why would my replicated code have performance issues? Is it because Object.create uses less resources when it's called directly in the engine sources C/C++ files, rather than by being mimicked at runtime in Javascript?

Comment: *“However, apparently creating a blank object with the required [[prototype]] means creating a normal blank object and then manually changing it.”* Apparently why? That’s how you *could* implement `Object.create`, but that’s not how it *is* implemented.

Comment: Ry, so basically tutorialspoint and various other sites are saying you can think of creating an object with a custom [[prototype]] by creating a blank object and changing its [[prototype]] from "Object.prototype" to "ConstructorFunction.prototype". However, what you are saying is that in the engine it is not creating a blank object with "Object.prototype" and changing it to "ConstructorFunction.prototype", it is just creating a blank object with "ConstructorFunction.prototype" straight off?

Comment: Create a JSperf snippet where the performance differences can be seen (or equivalent), otherwise volunteers looking to answer this have no data to start from

Comment: It's 2019, we have classes in JS, unless you have a _really well motivated_ reason to use Object.create, why are you asking this question instead of just creating normal objects and using performance monitoring tools to find the _real_ bottlenecks in your code? Esoteric performance differences in ES engines are neat trivia, but also pretty much irrelevant in almost every real code base.

Comment: Here goes a [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/prototype-changes/1) link.

Comment: "new " can be optimized by the JavaScript engine (e.g. v8), all the others depend on userland changes so it carries all the baggage of JS as a dynamic language, mostly that it runs inside a sandbox